# Correct procedure for PCA feature selection then Random Forest classification

Tags: python-3.x, random-forest, pca

After MFCC feature extraction, I am attempting on using PCA feature selection then carrying out classification using Random Forest.

Prior to `standardscale()` on the data, I have separated out the `X_train`, `y_train`, `X_test` and `y_test` data.

Step 1:  I firstly scale the data as follows:

```
scaler = StandardScaler()
X_train_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X_train.reshape(-1, X_train.shape[-1])).reshape(X_train.shape)
X_test_scaled = scaler.transform(X_test.reshape(-1, X_test.shape[-1])).reshape(X_test.shape)

# Flatten data for PCA
X_train_scaled = np.array([features_2d.flatten() for features_2d in X_train_scaled])
X_test_scaled = np.array([features_2d.flatten() for features_2d in X_test_scaled])
```

Step 2: Then I apply `PCA` and `PCA.fit` as follows:

```
pca_train = PCA().fit(X_train_scaled)
pca_train = PCA(n_components = index_95)      # Transformation into 31 principal components
x_pca_train = pca_train.fit_transform(X_train_scaled)

x_pca_test = pca_test.fit_transform(X_test_scaled)

X_train = x_pca_train
X_test = x_pca_test
```

Step 3: Carry out `Random Forest` classification.

I wanted to know if the procedure is correct in Step 1 and Step 2 for correct `standardscale` and `PCA` analysis for the `X_train` and `X_test` data.

Thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, PCA is not guaranteed to be useful for classification tasks (see e.g. [https://www.csd.uwo.ca/~oveksler/Courses/CS434a_541a/Lecture8.pdf](https://www.csd.uwo.ca/%7Eoveksler/Courses/CS434a_541a/Lecture8.pdf)).

I cannot say whether all the reshapes on the scaler step are needed without knowing your data, however step 2 certainly looks a bit off:

- Your first call to `pca_train = PCA().fit(X_train_scaled)` is redundant since you immediately redefine it afterwards.
- `x_pca_test = pca_test.fit_transform(X_test_scaled)` looks like a mistake, you should only fit train data and apply `transform()` to the test set.

Comment: thanks for your response!  As for your second point, even though I am sending the `X_train` and `X_test` to a `random forest` classifier in the next stage, the correct procedure is to have `x_pca_train = pca_train.fit_transform(X_train_scaled)` and then `x_pca_test = pca_train.transform(X_test_scaled)`?

Comment: Yes, as a rule of thumb, you should not `fit()` the test set anywhere.

Comment: Do you have any references I can consult (in tandem with your response) that I can use to read up more on concerning this matter?  Thanks again!

Comment: This is subjective, but Geron's _Hands-on Machine Learning_ textbook and its accompanying notebooks (like https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml2/blob/master/08_dimensionality_reduction.ipynb) cover a great deal of entrylevel practical cases.